# Java: Can you expose 3rd party interface from your own class

Tags: java, logging, interface, log4j, log4j2

We’re using log4j2 to do logging throughout our application and now I want to add some additional functions to the LogManager…at the same time, I hoped it would be possible to hide the “implementation details” of the LogManager for the rest of the application, so that instead of importing the log4j2 Logger everywhere, I can expose my own interface or class, from my own proprietary LogManager (that way, it would be possible to refactor or replace the way I store log messages without affecting the entire application).

I can create my own LogManager, called LM, easily like this:

```
package com.xxx.yyy.logging;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class LM extends LogManager {

  …add own methods here…

}
```

But when I call:

```
LM.getLogger(Application.class)
```

It returns an object of type org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger – is there an easy way to “wrap and expose” this interface via my own package, so that the rest of the application don’t have to be concerned with log4j?

I’ve tried something like:

```
package com.xxx.yyy.logging;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MessageFactory;

public class LMlogger extends org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger implements Logger {

    protected LMlogger(LoggerContext context, String name,
            MessageFactory messageFactory) {
        super(context, name, messageFactory);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
};
```

…in order to implement the class returned as well as the expected interface, but still I can’t “down-cast” the returned Logger-object to my own LMlogger (which makes sense, as my class is the sub-class). But is there another way to keep the log4j2 implemenation details in one place only, without having to wrap each and every method of the Logger-class?

Comment: You probably want to use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: What kind of additional functions? You'd probably be better off using SLF4J instead of rolling your own facade.

Comment: Could be simple stuff like getting a list of recent exceptions provided some filter...nothing I can't do without "hidding/wrapping" log4j, I just think it would be nice, that the rest of the app doesn't have to know about two LogManagers and doesn't have to have a tight coupling to a 3rd party lib

Comment: Reg. composition, then I would probably have to "wrap" all the methods of e.g. the Logger in my own LMlogger, and then call the corresponding Logger-method on the internal object (function x() { _logger.x(); } for all methods - I wondered if there's a way to avoid this?

Comment: (Ideally I would just make a typedef-kind of thing, and declare that the type com.xxx.yyy.logging.LMlogger is identical to org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger....wondered if there's a way to go about this in Java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [tool that log4j2 provides](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html#CustomLoggers) to generate custom Logger wrappers.

This tool was intended to add convenience methods for custom log levels or hide existing log levels, but you can use it for any purpose.

It also hides the LogManager from the client code (your app), and the generated code is in whatever package you specify, so client code won't be aware it is using log4j2.

You may need to regenerate the wrapper when you upgrade log4j2 after it had API changes (which is rare, but there will be additional API in 2.6).

Answer (score -1):

Look at the following way:

- Create a same-name Class `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager` in your project, and copy the source code of the original `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager` in log4j lib. Then edit the code and add what you want.
- `Logger` or other class in the same way.

**But you must make sure that your project must be loaded before the log4j lib.**